# Spring Integration - Annotation for HeaderValueRouter

Tags: spring-integration

How can I annotate a method so it processes messages for a specific header value?  I already have a HeaderValueRouter in XML config that routes to the appropriate class and executes the correct method based on the payload type.  I would like to annotate some methods in this class (specifically with no parameters) like this:

```
@Router(header("operation")="one")
public String getOne() {}

@Router(header("operation")="two")
public String getTwo() {}
```

The point of this is to enable a REST like service where the user can call a URL like ../service/one, and Spring Integration will set the operation header to "one". Basically I want to have the ability to quickly add methods to my web service and they automatically work by adding the above annotations to my underlying service.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such mechanism. Even if it looks interest I'm not sure that we should introduce that -it breaks some messaging concerns

Anyway with XML you have `<header-value-router>`, which has a `channel-mapping`. That one specifies where `to send` the message to invoke appropriate `service-activator`.

So, I suggest you do the same using annotations:

```
@MessagingGateway(defaultRequestChannel = "routerChannel")
public interface ServiceGateway {

    Object invoke(String operation);

}
....

@Autowired
private ServiceGateway serviceGateway;

@RequestMapping("/service/{operation}")
public Object operation(@PathVariable String operation) {
    return this.serviceGateway.invoke(operation);
}

@Router(inputChannel = "routerChannel")
public String route(String operation) {
    return operation;
}

...
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "one")
public String getOne() {}
...
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "two")
public String getTwo() {}
```